# code igniter personal form validation rule does not work

Tags: codeigniter, validation

I have this problem on Code Igniter, with a library containing my own validation rules (MY_Form_validation).
I want to check if a field is populate, only if another one is populate. Field2 is required only if field1 is filled.
Here the lines on my controller :

```
for($j = 1 ; $j < $i ; $j++) {
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('day' . $j, 'Jour ' . $j, 'dateIsPosteriorToField[start_date]|trim|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('alert' . $j, 'Alerte jour ' . $j, 'conditionalRequired[day' . $j . ']|trim|xss_clean');
}
```

(i have multiple fields like that, so I get them with a loop)

And my form validation :

```
function conditionalRequired($valueTocheck, $conditionalField)
{
    $this->set_message('conditionalRequired', 'Le champ %s est requis.');
    $conditionalValue = $this->CI->input->post($conditionalField);
    if( ! empty($conditionalValue) && empty($valueTocheck)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Problem : if field2 is filled, CI goes into the rule and match it. If field2 is empty, CI does NOT go into the rule. I can see that by dumping any value in the rule, it simply ignores the rule if field2 is empty.

There must be something obvious I don't see, please help me !

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the solution you are looking for but you could get around your problem by doing the following.

```
for($j = 1 ; $j < $i ; $j++) {
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('day' . $j, 'Jour ' . $j, 'dateIsPosteriorToField[start_date]|trim|xss_clean');
    if ($this->input->post('day' . $j)) {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('alert' . $j, 'Alerte jour ' . $j, 'required|trim|xss_clean');
    }
}
```

this way if the `'day' . $j` POST is set the `'alert' . $j` is set to be required.

Doing it like this means that you don't need to extend the form_validation class.

Comment: Thanks Mic, that will be my second choice, but as a developper I REALLY WANT to understand why it does not work ;)